# Mysql 5.6 trouble installing in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql

Why do i get mysql install error even after completely removing the mysql or purger it.

i get :

[image]

I did all possible ways of removing the mysql and reinstalling it, i am still facing the same issue.

Removed the etc/mysql files too.

Pls suggest

Comment: Usually, what is needed at this point is `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Did you try that?

Comment: yes i did try... post that i did apt-get update and clean all and also removed etc/mysql and tried reinstalling mysql, again ended up with the same

Comment: any update @Jos on this?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo dpkg --configure mysql-server-5.6`?

Comment: dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 no package named `mysql-server-5.6' is installed, cannot configure
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6   ...i had removed mysql-server, and also no sql related packages present, if i freshly install mysql, i still get the same above error